# Push notifications to mobile applications in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am working on a project in Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3 and I am looking for a gem to send push notifications to my iOS app and to my Android app.
 I found [speedy_c2dm](https://github.com/sghael/speedy_c2dm) for android worth useful.
But,I am concerned about as mentioned in [Migration to GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/c2dm.html):

> Android Cloud to Device Messaging (C2DM) is deprecated.  C2DM
>   developers are strongly encouraged to move to Google Cloud Messaging
>   (GCM)

Does [speedy_c2dm](https://github.com/sghael/speedy_c2dm) support [GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) ? Is there any other gem that supports new GCM ?
 Also, I want to know what is difference between [speedy_c2dm](https://github.com/sghael/speedy_c2dm) and [c2dm](https://github.com/amro/c2dm) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both speedy_c2dm and c2dm are just two libraries to send push notifications by using C2DM, they are written by different persons, they both work and there are not major differences, in theory speedy_c2dm should be faster, but there are not benchmarks at the moment.

Instead of implementing C2DM, you should implement GCM :)

There are many gcm gems, the most popular is gcm but last commit was 5 months ago:

[gcm](https://github.com/spacialdb/gcm)

[gcm_on_rails](https://github.com/dondeng/gcm_on_rails)

[pushgcm](https://rubygems.org/gems/push-gcm)

[simple_gcm](https://github.com/leobessa/simple_gcm)

[simple-gcm](http://github.com/snepo/simple-gcm)

[higcm](http://github.com/hifrank/higcm)

[speedygcm](https://github.com/sghael/speedy_gcm)

Comment: Thanks rorra.can you give similar gems for ios.

Comment: You can go to the ruby toolbox and gem a list of gems for Apple Push Notifications by searching for apn: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=apn

Comment: I know ruby toolbox well,but there are many XXXapn gems,I can't figure out which to use (can't just rely on num_of_downloads/active_period)?

Comment: In that case use https://github.com/ileitch/rapns, its a popular apn gem, works with rails 3 and ruby 1.9.3, its being used by big websites like desk.com and gateguru.com, and last commit was yesterday so its until active maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

Google "Cloud To Device Messaging" (c2dm) is called now "Google Cloud Messaging" (GCM). The old [c2dm_on_rails](https://github.com/pimeys/c2dm_on_rails) gem has been replaced by a [gcm_on_rails](https://github.com/dondeng/gcm_on_rails) gem, and the [speedy_c2dm](https://github.com/sghael/speedy_c2dm) gem has been replaced by the [speedy_gcm](https://github.com/sghael/speedy_gcm) gem. [gcm_on_rails](https://github.com/dondeng/gcm_on_rails) is similar to the popular [apn_on_rails](https://github.com/PRX/apn_on_rails) for Apple Push Notifications. Speedyc2dm and gcm_on_rails are both wrappers used to access the [GCM API](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

I just released a new version of rapns that supports both APNs and GCM: https://github.com/ileitch/rapns